# Ether transferred to Receiver's account is not exact

Tags: solidity, transactions, javascript, bignumber

I'm trying to transfer to send some ether from one account to another in a smart contract written in Solidity. The transfer is successful but the amount received is not exactly matching up with the amount transferred. There is a very minute difference, sometimes it is increasing and sometimes decreasing.

For Example -

```
received amount: 0.04999999999999716
Transferred amount: 0.05
```

Another example -

```
Received amount - 0.05000000000001137
Transferred amount -0.05
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Solidity function which does the transfer -

```
function borrowBook(uint id) onlyMember payable{
    // Can't borrow book if passed value is not sufficient
    if (msg.value < 100){
        throw;
    }
    // Can't borrow a non-existent book
    if (id > numBooks || catalog[id].state != State.Available) {
        throw;
    }
    catalog[id].borrower = msg.sender;
    catalog[id].dateIssued = now;
    catalog[id].state = State.Borrowed;
    // 50% value is shared with the owner
    var owner_share = msg.value/2; 
    if (!catalog[id].owner.send(owner_share)){
        throw;
    }
    Borrow(id, msg.sender, catalog[id].dateIssued);
}
```

Test case where I'm checking the balances of sender and receiver -

```
    it.only('should borrow book and transfer 50% weis to owner account', async function(){
        await lms.addBook('a', 'b', 'c');
        await lms.addMember('Michael Scofield', accounts[2]);
        // balance of owner and borrower's account before book borrow
        let ownerBal1 = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]).valueOf());
        let borrowBal1 = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[2]).valueOf());
        await lms.borrowBook(1, {from: accounts[2], value: web3.toWei(0.1)});
        // balance of owner and borrower's account after book borrow
        let ownerBal2 = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]).valueOf());
        let borrowBal2 = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[2]).valueOf());
        let contractBal = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(lms.address).valueOf());
        // contract account get's 50% of the value
        assert.equal(contractBal, 0.05);
        // owner's account should get increased by approx 50% of sent value
        console.log(ownerBal2 - ownerBal1);
        console.log(0.05);
        console.log(borrowBal1-borrowBal2);
        assert.isAtMost(ownerBal2 - ownerBal1, 0.05);
        // borrower's account shoul d get decreased by atleat total sent value
        assert.isAtLeast(borrowBal1 - borrowBal2, 0.1);
    });
```

Comment: Probably due to JS floating point precision and a suggestion is to keep values in BigNumber (rather than converting to strings and doing computations on them).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was taking valueOf every time. With removing valueOf at variable declaration fixed this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When possible, keep values in [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) to avoid Javascript precision and number limits.  Try to avoid using `valueOf()`, and prefer to operate using BigNumber methods when needed.

So more precise code is like:

```
let ownerBal1 = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]));
```

and

```
ownerBal2.sub(ownerBal1);
```